# Blackberry Model Differences

Tags: java, blackberry

Are there specific classes( or anything code-related really) that just doesn't work on some models of blackberries but does on others?
If so, can someone please give me some examples of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html

you will see the blackberry api 5.0.

you can then turn on frames and in the packages box select any of the net.rim.* packages to see which version of the api there are available from.

Example

> **net.rim.blackberry.api.browser**
>
> Class Browser
>
> java.lang.Object
>   net.rim.blackberry.api.browser.Browser
>   public final class Browser extends
>   Object Provides access to the
>   BlackBerry Browser.
>
> To gain access to the BlackBerry
>   Browser application, use
>   Browser.getDefaultSession() or
>   Browser.getSession(java.lang.String)
>   to retrieve a BrowserSession object
>   you can use to direct the application
>   to load pages.
>
> Category: Signed: This element is only
>   accessible by signed applications. If
>   you intend to use this element, please
>   visit
>   http://www.blackberry.com/go/codesigning
>   to obtain a set of code signing keys.
>   Code signing is only required for
>   applications running on BlackBerry
>   smartphones; development on BlackBerry
>   Smartphone Simulators can occur
>   without code signing. 
>   **Since: BlackBerry API 4.0.0**

Comment: Thanks. this has proven very helpful

Answer (score 2):

I think some more information is needed to really answer this question effectively, but here's what my experience has been in the past few months of beginning BB development.

There are different OS versions on different devices, which will provide different versions of the RIM Java API, some of which do and do not have certain classes.  An example from my own experience is the Display.screenshot() method which takes a snapshot of the screen, I believe this is not available versions of the RIM API previous to 4.3.

There are also a few touch-screen Blackberries which of course have a different interface, and so there are concerns there, but I'm not sure if this is really relevant since the OS version might be a bigger deal. For instance certain classes such as TouchEvent are only supported in newer versions of the API which are on the touch devices as well as newer non-touch devices.  So an app running with both touch and non-touch interfaces will work on both kinds of devices provided they have a recent OS... dependent of course on the application design to use the right UI code for the right device.